# How function call is working on an unitialized data member object in constructor's initilalizer list

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Consider below program,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() { cout << "A constructor\n"; }
    void f()
    {
       cout << "A used\n";
       this->i++;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A & a1)
    {
        cout << "B constructor\n";
        a1.f();
    }
};

class Z
{
public:
    Z() :  a_(), b_(a_) {}
private:
    B b_;
    A a_;
};

int main() {
    Z z;
    return 0;
}
```

Below is output it produces,

```
B constructor
A used
A constructor
```

My Question,

Since data member objects are created in order of their declaration in class, hence `b_` will be created first. But how it is able to call a function on data member `a_` which is still not created? Does compiler performs some kind of optimization to translate call to `f()` to a plain function call? If yes, then how `this->i++` is working?

Comment: Undefined behaviour probably.

Comment: UB make anything could happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler won't fight you when you explicitly instruct it to pass a reference to an uninitialized object somewhere. After all, the function you pass it to may be used to actually initialize the object.

However, accessing uninitialized data, e.g., your `this->i++;`, results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Then, It means that memory for both a_ and b_ is allocated prior to constructor of any of them is invoked, right?

Comment: @pravar Yes. When construction of an object starts, memory for the entire object is allocated (of course, that doesn't include any memory dynamically allocated by any of the constructors).